# How do you read XXX (replacement for unknown characters in a name, etc.)?

Tags: characters, reading

[image]

The screenshot is from a book about Lin Biao. I wonder how the `XXX` in `XXX同志` (roughly *Comrade XYZ* or *Comrade So-and-So*) would be read, if someone were to read it out aloud. Do you read the `X` as 某?

Also, is there a proper CJK Unicode character for the `X`?

Comment: If your question is how to pronounce XXX, just say 叉叉叉(chā chá chǎ).

Answer (score 2):

XXX同志 shall be read as "某某"同志.

Comment: I don't think there is such a rule or even convention. I would rather use 某同志 instead. 某某 Or 某某某 is sort of indicating the number of characters of the name. That makes people even more curious about who actually is that person, which is bad.